# Calculating the probability of a duplicate result within a subset of possibilities (Gacha gaming)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gambling

I play Marvel Strike Force and was discussing the probabilities of having a duplicate result on an lootbox. However. I feel like maybe I'm doing something wrong.

You open the lootbox/orb and you get the following chances (it's detailed by the game devs):

- 10% 7 stars pull
- 90% 6 red stars pull

Consider this your bags/pools. In the 10% pool you have the following probabilities:

- 0,60% to get a 7 red star for one of 141 characters
- 3% to get a 7 red star for one of 5 characters

Now let's say you get pool for 7 red star for one of the 141 characters. I would presume the probability of having a duplicate would be:

- P(10% - getting in the 10% bag) x P(0,60% - getting one of the 141
  characters) = 0,006% then
- P(getting a second pull with one of the 141    characters) => 0,006^2
  = 0,000032% then
- P(pulling a duplicate 7 red    star on the second pull) => 0,000032 x P(probability of having this specific 7RS on your rooster)
- P(probability of having this specific    7RS on your rooster) = 1/141
  ??

Are my steps right or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Some clarifications as requested. You have multiple characters on your [rooster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax0QN.jpg) that can evolve up to 7 Yellow stars. On top of those stars you have Red Stars that go on top of those Yellow. The way they do it is a bit complex. Imagine that red stars is something you equip in the character itself.

This question is regarding Red Stars only and a specific orb (out of the multiple orbs that give you red star rewards). The specific orb works like this (although you basically just click *open* button and all the calculations are done on their side):

- You click *open* and you get either a 6 Star or a 7 star. That's the base action->result. Example 7 Red Star result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGTGI.jpg).
- After that open action, internally, your pool/bag is selected (6 or 7 red stars pool) with RNG. The 6 vs 7 Star pool selection probability is in the first in my first list (90% vs 10%).
- Both pools/bags have Red Stars for 146 characters. 141 characters have a 0.60% chance and the other 5 characters have a 3% chance.

In short, let's say you open the orb, in its current state, you will probably have a 6 red star result (90%) for a character pulled.

So, my question is for the scenario where you open this specific orb/lootbox two times, what are the chances of having a duplicate for the 141 characters on the second opening given you have no character in your rooster with 7 red stars.

Also, keep in mind my percentages here are based on what the developers state in the orb/lootbox description.

Comment: This is really hard to understand for someone unfamiliar with the game. You talk about lootbox, orb, pull, bag, pool, star, and rooster. It seems like “a 7 red star” is a thing that can be on a pull or a rooster, but there are different kinds of 7RS? . To the extent possible, it would help to list the actual steps and all possible results and probabilities, but I feel like you're pretty far from that. Even what “a duplicate result on a lootbox” means isn't very clear.

Comment: @SteveKass I'm added the process of opening along with some images. Don't focus too much on the system though because you either get one of two things: A 7 or a 6 red star for a specific toon. Hope it helps!